# What is the difference between 'at least' and 'in the least'?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is the difference between 'at least' and 'in the least'? What does 'in the least patient' mean?

> I'm not **in the least** patient.

A WIND in the DOOR by MADELEINE L’ENGLE

Comment: What in the [dictionary explanation](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/least) doesn't work  for you? (Scroll down to the "idioms" section.)

Comment: So as I understand it means - I'm not patient at all.

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted, but this is a good example of why we ask folks to [share their research](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please). I can understand that a learner may not know that "in the least" is idiomatic. However, when you don't at least tell us what you looked up and share what you found, then it's hard to tell if you tried to find the meaning but didn't realize it was an idiom, or if you simply didn't even want to bother with a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both expressions "least" means "the smallest amount, number, or degree".

> You should at least take a sweater.

This means "The smallest amount of clothing which you should take with you when you go out is a sweater."

> I must owe you at least ten dollars.

This means "I am sure I owe you ten dollars, probably more."

> I am not in the least patient.

I am not patient even to the smallest degree.

> You have not inconvenienced me in the least.

This means "To me this was not even the smallest inconvenience."

Answer (score -1):

As you have mentioned @Vitaly this can be as interpreted as:

> I'm not patient at all.